# Redirection to Gateway using Haproxy on two different ports

Tags: reverse-proxy

Here our scenario where we want to work using HAProxy

```
(client) -> example.com -> (redirect) -> example.com
(client) -> example.com:8080 -> (redirect) -> example.com:8080
```

This is Possible in haproxy or not, plz try to reply as fast as possible

Comment: I'm sorry, I've read and reread your question and can't really figure out what you want to accomplish. Further, here at SF, we expect you to have tried something and come here with specific issues to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do this using haproxy. You can define two frontends / backends sections, as long as the IP+port you're listening on don't overlap.